# Hardhat throwing 'missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string'

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, web3-providers, binance-smart-chain, arbitrage

After installing Hardhat's npm package latest version following [**this**](https://hardhat.org/getting-started#installation) brief guide and setting up my first '*sample project*', i tried to create a script and deploy a contract on the BSC mainnet. I edited the **hardhat.config.js** file in order to do that in this way:

```js
      module.exports = {
      defaultNetwork: "bnbmainnet",
      networks: {
        hardhat: {
        },
        bnbmainnet: {
          url: "https://bsc-dataseed1.defibit.io/",
          accounts: ["privateKey"]
        }
      },
      solidity: "0.7.6"
    };
```

I took the BSC JSON-RPC Endpoint from the [**ufficial page**](https://docs.bnbchain.org/docs/rpc/), so should be fine; i should also be under their requests limit of 8K/5min.

Then i took from [**here**](https://github.com/yuyasugano/pancake-bakery-arbitrage/blob/main/contracts/Flashswap.sol) the Flashbot.sol script from here, which retrieves some pair infos (primarly price) from UniswapV2 fork on the BSC network and then successfully deployed it to mainnet.

The script i created to interact with the contract is this:

```js
    const { ethers } = require('hardhat');
    
    const BNB_MAINNET = '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c';
    const BUSD_MAINNET = '0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56';
    
    const pancake =
    {
        name : "pancakeswap",
        router: "0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e",
        factory: "0xca143ce32fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fc5350c73",
    };
    
    const knightswap = {
        name : "knightswap",
        router: "0x05E61E0cDcD2170a76F9568a110CEe3AFdD6c46f",
        factory: "0xf0bc2E21a76513aa7CC2730C7A1D6deE0790751f"
    };
    
    const dexes = [ pancake, babyswap, knightswap, biswap, bakeryswap];
    
    const pair = 
        {
            name: 'BNB to BUSD',
            amountTokenPay: ["0.1","0.5", "1", "2", "5", "10", "20", "50", "100","200", "500", "1000"],
            tokenPay: BNB_MAINNET,
            tokenSwap: BUSD_MAINNET
        }
    
    let flashswap, Flashswap, sign;
    
    (async () => {
    
        sign = await ethers.getSigner("signerAccount");
        
        Flashswap = await ethers.getContractFactory("Flashswap");
        
        flashswap = await new ethers.Contract("contractAddress", Flashswap.interface, sign);
    })();
    
    const init = async () => {
    
        pair.amountTokenPay.forEach(async (qnt) => {
        
            dexes.forEach(async (dex) => {
                try 
                {
                    if(dex != dexes[0]){
                        const check = await flashswap.check(pair.tokenPay, pair.tokenSwap, ethers.utils.parseUnits(qnt, 18), dexes[0].router, dex.router);
                        var profit = check[0]/10e18;
                        if(profit >= 0)
                            console.log(`pair: ${pair.name} -> ${dex.name}, amount: ${qnt}, profit: ${profit}.`);
                    }
                }
                catch (e)
                {
                    console.log("Something went wrong with the execution of check method. \n " + e);
                    process.exit(-1);
                }                    
            });
        });
    }
    
    ethers.provider.on("block", (blk) => {
        init();
    });
```

Essentally calling the check method of the contract for each new block created and doing some basic arbitrage operations.
This code actually runs correctly, but no matter what, after a certain point it will throw the error:

```
Error: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason 
string [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (data="0x", transaction=
{"from":"","to":"","data":"0xc08757bc000000000000000000000000bb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9
173bc095c000000000000000000000000e9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d560000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000001bc16d674ec8000000000000000000000000000010ed43c718714eb63d5aa57
b78b54704e256024e000000000000000000000000cde540d7eafe93ac5fe6233bee57e1270d3e330f","accessLi
st":null}, error={"name":"ProviderError","code":-32603,"_isProviderError":true},
code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.6.8)
```

And i'm really struggling to understand what does that means;
The last mentioned error -32603 according to the JSON-RPC [**specification**](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#response_object) means '*Internal JSON-RPC error.*' which obviously can't help, nor the Hardhat [**error**](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/troubleshooting/errors/#help-CALL_EXCEPTION) which is quite general too, so hope you can!

Comment: Looks like using a Websocket provider solved the issue.